# What fuses do I need?

Tags: fuses

I was trying to post a photo but it doesn't seem to like it
I am repairing an electric fireplace, the fuse seems to be blown. It is a classic glass fuse with a long strand down the center. It says 25A 125V on the one end. Is there a difference between the slow and fast blow fuses and how do I know which I need? It's my first time on this forum and just thought this might be the place to ask!

thanks in advance!

Comment: google `slo blo fuse` and look at the pictures

Comment: The instructions for the electric fire should tell you what to fit.

Comment: I would suggest taking it to a repair shop. The fuse with the long strand down the center would be broken if blown, but that is not always visible. Use an ohm meter to validate the fuse.  Replace with the same type of fuse, if you do not you will be compromising safety. If you gave us the make and model that would help us help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would say T25A for a slow blow fuse, so it's probably a regular fuse.